QGIS Network analysis: Consideration of heights
I want to calculate isochrones in QGIS from a location X (for example, a catchment area of 900 metres). We use our own dataset of footpaths for this. So far, this has worked very well with the network analysis tool.
Now we also want to take the difference in altitude into account by adding 1000 metres to the path length for every 100 metre difference in altitude. We use an elevation model for this. And this is where we get stuck. Can anyone help me?


